# How can I count repetitions of cpf in determinate day?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have the folowing dataframe:

```
cpf  day  startdate              enddate
1234  1   08/01/2018 12:50:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 14:30:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0
1234  2   08/02/2018 20:20:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0
1234  2   08/02/2018 22:50:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0
1235  1   08/01/2018 11:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0
5212  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0
```

I need to calculate conversation time of cpf column in one day. For example, the first cpf is 1234, so in day 1 this cpf initiate a conversation on 08/01/2018 12:50:0 and the end of conversation was 08/01/2018 15:50:0, what I need is exactly this substraction about enddate - startdate. How can I do this?

```
  cpf  day  startdate              enddate              Time_Conversation
    1234  1   08/01/2018 12:50:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0         3:00:0
    1234  1   08/01/2018 14:30:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0         3:00:0
    1234  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0         3:00:0
    1234  2   08/02/2018 20:20:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0         3:30:0
    1234  2   08/02/2018 22:50:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0         3:30:0
    1235  1   08/01/2018 11:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0         4:30:0
    5212  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0         4:30:0
```

Comment: see the desired output in the answer..

Comment: The answers didnt looked to output, I need the difference of a CPF in entire day, for example, catch first contact and subtract with last contact and atribute to others cpf

Comment: Okay , hope you will get your answers from experts !

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a few things, but assuming the `startdate` and `enddate` are `pandas.Timestamp` columns, you could simply do:

```
df["Time_Conversation"] = (df["enddate"] - df["startdate"]).astype("timedelta64[s]")
```

This will give you the total number of seconds that the conversation went on. Then additionally format this to hh:mm:ss if you need.

If `startdate` and `enddate` a string type columns, you'll need to additionally convert to to a proper format.

```
import pandas as pd
df["startdate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["startdate"], infer_datetime_format=True)
df["enddate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["enddate"] ,infer_datetime_format=True)

df["Time_Conversation"] = (df["enddate"] - df["startdate"]).astype("timedelta64[s]")
```

Answer (score 0):

First Convert the date strings to pandas.Timestamps:

```
>>> df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'])
>>> df['enddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'])

>>> df["Time_Conversation"] = df['enddate']-df['startdate']
>>> df
    cpf  day           startdate             enddate Time_Conversation
0  1234    1 2018-08-01 12:50:00 2018-08-01 15:50:00   0 days 03:00:00
1  1234    1 2018-08-01 14:30:00 2018-08-01 15:50:00   0 days 01:20:00
2  1234    1 2018-08-01 14:50:00 2018-08-01 15:50:00   0 days 01:00:00
3  1234    2 2018-08-01 20:20:00 2018-08-02 23:50:00   1 days 03:30:00
4  1234    2 2018-08-01 22:50:00 2018-08-02 23:50:00   1 days 01:00:00
5  1235    1 2018-08-01 11:50:00 2018-08-01 15:20:00   0 days 03:30:00
6  5212    1 2018-08-01 14:50:00 2018-08-01 15:20:00   0 days 00:30:00
```

***Note:*** Passing `infer_datetime_format=True` can often-times speedup a parsing if its not an ISO8601 format exactly, but in a regular format, In some cases this can increase the parsing speed by ~5-10x.

Hence, we can use that as well ..

```
df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['enddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```